# Read only parquet column names in R

Tags: r, parquet

I am looking to get only the column names from a parquet file (with partitioning) using the arrow package in R. My hope is to have a vector of only the column names. I am able to do this using collect, however working with larger multi partition and multi file parquets takes longer than expected. Here is an example of what I have and hoping to achieve.

Create parquet with partion (some may have multiple partitions)

```
arrow::write_dataset(mtcars, "C:/Data/parquet/mtcars", format = "parquet", partitioning = c("cyl"))
```

Current way to get parquet column names

```
colnames(arrow::open_dataset(sources = "C:/Data/parquet/mtcars") %>%
  dplyr::collect())
```

Result of using colnames with collect

```
[1] "mpg"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb" "cyl"
```

I feel there is a more efficient way to get parquet column names without doing a collect. End goal to have a vector like above. Open to options and ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/Dataset.html#methods), the Dateset object has got a schema method from which you can get the [columns names](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/Schema.html#active-bindings).

I think it should be something like that:

```
arrow::open_dataset(sources = "C:/Data/parquet/mtcars")$schema$names
```

This will only load the metadata of the dataset and should be much faster thant loading all the data.

Comment: Thank you for this, its great.
I found a work around:
colnames(as.data.frame(arrow::open_dataset(sources = "C:/Data/parquet/mtcars")[1,])) and someone on Twitter recommended names(arrow::open_dataset(sources = "C:/Data/parquet/mtcars")), but your solution seems much better and faster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a single file parquet, then the following wrapper function on functions that exists in R-arrow library will work for you:

```
read_parquet_schema <- function (file, col_select = NULL, as_data_frame = TRUE, props = ParquetArrowReaderProperties$create(), 
                                 ...) 
{
  require(arrow)
  reader <- ParquetFileReader$create(file, props = props, ...)
  schema <- reader$GetSchema()
  names <- names(schema)
  return(names)
}
```

Example:

```
arrow::write_parquet(iris,"iris.parquet")
read_parquet_schema("iris.parquet")
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `parquet` file can also readable with `lapply` and `rbindlist` like

```
data.table::rbindlist(lapply(Sys.glob("C:/Data/parquet/mtcars/*/part-*.parquet"), arrow::read_parquet)) %>% colnames
```

but with `open_dataset` and `collect` seems fore efficient.